# How to pass Dynamic value in @Where in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager

I want to filter entity by using @Where and want to know how to pass dynamic value in JPA

Example : @Where(clause = "name = 'Alas'") //Here  'Alas' is static i want to make it dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make the structure of the `WHERE` clause itself dynamic in this way.  Assuming you want to make certain portions of the `WHERE` clause dynamic, you could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE name = ? OR ? IS NULL;
```

To the `?` placeholders above, you would bind `'Alas'`.  If you don't pass any value, then the crtierion on `name` would simply be ignored.

Comment: Thanks,But my requirement is : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72909639/how-to-apply-where-clause-on-nested-child-two-level-nested-in-jpa?noredirect=1#comment128777298_72909639